How to normalize a signal after Blackman-Harris window?
I have applied a Blackman-Harris window to a real-valued signal.
Is there a way to normalize it perfectly after the windowing or relatively good way to keep the same power?
Thank you for an answer in advance.

This question is similar to: What is the energy`correction or amplitude correction for a Tukey window?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The two normalizations I use depend on if the signal is narrowband, specifically with all energy less than the resolution bandwidth of the measurement and window used (such as single tones) or broadband where the energy of the waveform spans beyond the resolution bandwidth (such as broadband noise or modulated waveforms).
With that, I use what I refer to as an "FFT Spectrum" for measurement of individual frequency tones, and the Welch Spectral Density for the measurement of broadband waveforms and noise as power spectral densities. The highlights of each approach are detailed below.
FFT Spectrum for accurately measuring individual tones
With this approach, window the waveform, and then apply zero padding which will significantly reduce variation in the measurement due to scalloping loss. I recommend padding out to four to ten times the length of the waveform which reduces the scalloping loss to less than 0.01 dB typically when a good window is used (personally I recommend the Kaiser window).
And then after computing the FFT, scale the result by the sum of the window coefficients such that the maximum bin value will accurately represent the coefficient of the exponential frequency (a real cosine consists of two coefficients given $\cos(\omega t) = 0.5e^{j\omega t}+0.5e^{-j\omega t}$. Thus this approach given will result in the accurate 0.5 magnitude for the two bins resulting from the FFT of a cosine (for example). This is summarized in the graphic below:

With the following demonstration showing the very high precision result where I used a frequency that would have the worst scalloping loss:

Resolution Bandwidth of the Measurement
An important result to present with every spectrum is the resolution bandwidth of the measurement (so the equivalent noise bandwidth of every FFT bin), and this is given by the formula below:
$$B = N\frac{\sum(w[n]^2}{(\sum(w[n])^2}$$
Where $B$ is the bandwidth in number of bins $N$ of the original sequence, not the zero padded length, and $w[n]$ is the window coefficients.
The resolution bandwidth in Hz would then be $Bf_s/N$.
Welch Spectral Density for Noise and Wideband Waveforms
For noise and modulated waveforms that span multiple FFT bins, I recommend a power spectral density (with units of power/Hz) rather than the direct FFT Spectrum as detailed above. The good news is the welch function available in MATLAB, Octave and Python's scipy.signal all accurately scale the result using the following scaling factor, so no actual further scaling is needed (but included below for reference):
$$k = \frac{1}{f_s \sum(w[n]^2)}$$
Where $f_s$ is the sampling rate and $w_n$ is the window coefficients.
Note this is a power scaling with the result from the welch function returning the power quantity (so 10Log10 used to convert to dB) in contrast to the magnitude scaling (with 20Log10) as I used earlier for the FFT Spectrum. Together with being divided by the sampling rate to provide a density in power/Hz in the same units of frequency as used for the sampling rate.
Below demonstrates an application where I used both results to determine the SNR (and from that the effective number of bits or ENOB) for the A/D conversion of a single sinusoid. Note how the FFT spectrum accurately presents the power level of the tones and the Welch spectrum very accurately presents the power level of the noise as a density (but not the tones since the power as given is spread over the resolution bandwidth of the measurement to provide the accurate noise density):

